# Checking the points where a given function is continuous and differentiable

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Given the function
$f(x)=x^2$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $0$ otherwise.
Find the points in which $f$ is continuous and the points in which $f(x)$ is differentiable.

For continuity,

If $f$ is continuous at $x$, let $x_n \in \mathbb{Q}$, $y_n\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x_n\to x$, and $y_n\to x$. Then
$x_n^2=f(x_n)\to f(x),0=f(y_n)\to f(x)$.
Since $x_n\to 0, 0\to p$ so by the uniqueness of limit we have that $x^2=f(x)=0$ so $x=0$.
Can then we say that $f$ is not continuous at $x\neq 0$?

For differentiability,
If $f$ is not continuous at $x\neq 0$ then it is not differentiable at $x\neq0$.
So we just need to check differentiability at $x=0$,
Is it just enough to show by def: let $h\in \mathbb{R}$,
$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h-0}= \lim_{h\to 0} f(h)/h$ since $f(0)=0$ so do we have to consider here two cases $h\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $h\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Yes, to both questions. And for the continuity, you can say that $f$ is continuous at $0$. For differentiability you should get that it is differentiable also at $0$.

Comment: For the differentiablity just to consider the two case I mentioned and find that the derivative is 0?

Comment: Yes, $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: continuos $\to$ continuous.

Comment: After I showed continuity in the above way, do I need to show it again by def? And look at two where $x_n$ gets rational/irrational values for $n>N$ and the other case when $x_n$ gets infinite values of rational and irrational ? @user85667

Answer (score 1):

For your differential case,  you have the function is either $h^2$ or $0$ so you have the quotient is either $0$ or $h$.   So, to keep the output within $\epsilon$ of $0$,  you just need to keep $h$ within $\epsilon$ of 0 as well, so you set $\delta=\epsilon$ and you are done

Comment: We can also show this by heine def right?

Comment: what is heine def?

Comment: If $0\neq x_n\to 0$ then $f(x_n)\to L$ @Alan

Comment: Sure, every point evaluates to either $0$ or $h$, so as $h\to 0$,  $h$ or $0$ goes to 0